# pass array to a class as an argument

Tags: java, arrays, class, arguments

I am trying to pass an array to another class as an argument but keep getting the error
 "error: incompatible types: Point cannot be converted to int[]"

the first portion of my code is:

```
public Circle(int n, int x, int y)
    {
        radius = n;
        counter++;
        center[0] = x;
        center[1] = y;


        Point center = new Point(center);


    }
```

Point is the class that needs to have the array passed to it.

the second portion of code:

```
public class Point 
{
    private int xCord;
    private int yCord;

    public Point (int [] center)

    {
        xCord = center[0];
        yCord = center[1];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unclear to me, however it should clearly cause an error in the circle class constructor.

```
center[0] = x; // center is an int array
center[1] = y;
Point center = new Point(center); // ?????
//     ^^^                ^^^^ Duplicate variable names
```

Fix this by changing the name of the new `Point` variable.

Answer (score 0):

`Point center = new Point(center);`
Duplicate variable
Change to
`Point point = new Point(center);`

Answer (score -1):

You have to consider Object here. The variable name here is duplicate. As the center objects hold the array reference you cannot keep the same variable to hold the point object.

You can modify your code accordingly. Attached you sample code

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Circle(1,2,3);

    }

    static void Circle(int n, int x, int y)
    {   int center[] = new int[2];
        //Do your operation and initialize the array
        center[0] = 25;
        center[1] = 26;
        Point pointObject = new Point(center);

    }   


}


class Point 
{
    private int xCord;
    private int yCord;

    public Point (int [] center)

    {
        xCord = center[0];
        yCord = center[1];

    }
}
```